# I am trying to use GII feature in YII, but it gives me error when I am opening the gii page

Tags: php, yii

It gives me error.

Error 403
You are not allowed to access this page.

I have uncommented this code in the main.php file inside protected directory.

```
'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'admin',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/115/why-do-i-get-a-403-error-when-trying-to-use-gii/

You need to add your ip address to the 'ipFilters' array

```
'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1', 'your_ip_address')
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you accessing gii using `localhost`? Are you able to access your local webserver using `localhost`? You cannot access your webserver by using `localhost` if you haven't mapped `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` which most of the times done by-default for you depending upon your system and the way you installed `php / apache`

Comment: I think you are right. Anyways I have fixed the problem. The problem the server is shared in a network environment and to access GII i have to give permission for my own ip after 127.0.0.1 I have adde my machine IP and its work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','*.*.*.*')
```

and then close it or change it back  afterwards...

because
if you don't...
kiddies will take you down